# Using Negative Tolerance Values with =IF(ABS) Formulae

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am working on a Quality Assurance Document for an Engineering firm where they can check the measurements of their manufactured items against the relevant drawings.

Below I have the current table I am working on and some context

1. **Column 1**: Data to be Manually Entered during Measurement Exercise
2. **Column 2**: Data pulled from a separate sheet using a VLOOKUP
3. **Column 3**: Data pulled from a separate sheet uasing a VLOOKUP
4. **Column 4**: Results obtained by using =IF(ABS), Specifically; =IF(ABS(B11-C11)<=D11, "Pass","Fail")

[image: Example of current work sheet]

As you can see, whenever there is a negative tolerance the formula presents a 'Fail' even if the unit is within the tolerance. So I am assuming there is something wrong with the formula. Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Remember minus with minus equal sum. So 50.7-(-0,05) actually is 50.07+0.05 = 50.12, which is greater than 11, so it fails

Comment: If you use `ABS()` on the substraction, use `ABS()` on the negative reference. Otherwise a positive number is always greater than a negative one; thus would "Fail".

Comment: Wrap an `ABS` around your tolerance value.

Comment: By Wrapping an ABS are you stating make it =ABS(-0.05) or using the $ to make it an absolute?

Comment: @MatthewPerryman, the former.

Comment: `=IF(ABS(A2-B2)<=ABS(C2);"Pass";"Fail")`

Comment: @JvdV perfect, that fixes the problem!